# Installing TeX Live and Texmaker or Kile under openSUSE Leap 42.1

Tags: texlive, texmaker, kile

I'm under openSUSE Leap 42.1

I installed TeX Live :

```
 sudo zypper in texlive
```

Then I try to install texlive-latex but it seems that texlive package is a full package because that say me texlive-latex is already installed.

```
sudo zypper in texlive-latex
```

I don't know if it's an update or if it's a difference between debian based distros and SUSE ones, but there isn't texlive-full or texlive-latex-extra.

Than I installed Texmaker and restarted my computer.

Once restarted I launched Texmaker and try to create and compile a document name maths.tex.

But whe compiling I have this error :

```
Process started

warning: kpathsea: /etc/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /var/cache/texmf/fonts/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

warning: kpathsea: /etc/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.

warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R. warning: kpathsea: /var/cache/texmf/fonts/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R. warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.

tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?). fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.

Process exited with error(s)
```

LaTeX command is :

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

And PdfLaTeX is :

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

That seems to be default ones.

After that I installed Kile which installed a lot a sub-package of texlive.

```
sudo zypper in kile
```

And when compiling I have similar error :

```
*****
*****     PDFLaTeXsortie: 
*****     cd "/home/shark/Documents"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode D_maths.tex
*****
warning: kpathsea: /etc/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: /var/cache/texmf/fonts/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
warning: kpathsea: /etc/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: /usr/share/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: /var/cache/texmf/fonts/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
warning: kpathsea: See the manual for how to generate ls-R.
tcfmgr: config file `tcfmgr.map' (usually in $TEXMFMAIN/texconfig) not found (ls-R missing?).
fmtutil: config file `fmtutil.cnf' not found.
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

My "/etc/texmf/ls-R" contains :

```
% ls-R -- filename database for kpathsea; do not change this line.
./:
```

### Additional informations

texlive

```
Informations sur package texlive :
----------------------------------
Dépôt : openSUSE-leap/42.1-Oss
Nom : texlive
Version : 2013.20130620-24.7
Arch : x86_64
Fabricant : openSUSE
Installé : Oui
État : A jour
Taille une fois installé : 124,3 KiB
```

texmaker

```
Informations sur package texmaker :
-----------------------------------
Dépôt : openSUSE-leap/42.1-Oss
Nom : texmaker
Version : 4.4.1-2.3
Arch : x86_64
Fabricant : openSUSE
Installé : Oui
État : A jour
Taille une fois installé : 33,6 MiB
```

texlive-latex

```
Informations sur package texlive-latex :
----------------------------------------
Dépôt : openSUSE-leap/42.1-Oss
Nom : texlive-latex
Version : 2013.84.svn27907-17.5
Arch : noarch
Fabricant : openSUSE
Installé : Oui
État : A jour
Taille une fois installé : 1,1 MiB
```

kile

```
Informations sur package kile :
-------------------------------
Dépôt : openSUSE-leap/42.1-Oss
Nom : kile
Version : 2.1.3-8.7
Arch : x86_64
Fabricant : openSUSE
Installé : Oui
État : A jour
Taille une fois installé : 5,6 MiB
```

Comment: Use the direct installer of `TeXLive` (vanilla) and download the relevant packages. It will be more up - to - date then the prepackaged version by the Linux distribution (I am using OpenSuSE 13.2)

Comment: Welcome! This is either a problem with the configuration of your system or a packaging problem in openSUSE which should be reported to them. I'd recommend not using their packages and installing from upstream, frankly, but the packages would create ls-R appropriately on installation.

Comment: Please open a console and type `which tlmgr`. If it is not ~/home/..., you probably have to type `sudo tlmgr gui`. You'll get the texlive manager and under "actions" create the ls-R files.

Comment: @Keks Dose
`$ sudo which tlmgr
which: no tlmgr in (/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
$ sudo tlmgr gui
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
`
It seems that `tlmgr` is not installed

Comment: @ChristianHupfer 
@cfr
The `vanilla` install is for Debian based distros, not for openSUSE so.
But may be you wanted to tell me to install [TeXLive over the internet](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)

Comment: So i'm doing the "medium install" + HTML of TeXLive over the Internet

Comment: @GetGit: Well, `vanilla` is TL over the net - install for me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer
All I found about `vanilla` on tug is ONLY for debian [https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally,
I installed TeXLive from the official website : [Installing TeX Live over the Internet](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)
and I followed the [TeX Live - Quick install](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) documentation.

That should have worked with the ditros package too I think.

In fact I just needed to set up the paths in Texmaker parameters for LaTeX and pdfLaTeX and others paths ...

So with my install bin was in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux`.

And it's better don't forget to modify the $PATH envrionnement variable. By adding :

`PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH` in my bash.rc profile

Answer (score 1):

Same kind of issue after upgrading the main `texlive` shipped with `openSUSE Leap-15.3` (2017 version) with the 2021 version from [Publishing:TeXLive](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/Publishing:TeXLive/texlive):

```
warning: kpathsea: /var/lib/texmf/ls-R: No usable entries in ls-R.
```

Solved by

```bash
sudo /usr/share/texmf/texconfig/update
```

cf. https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1046277